# FOUND multiprocessing.py file NEVERMIND! multiprocessing runs one USB but not on main drive

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

1. Mac Air and iMAC have same configuration as far as I know. 2.7.1 python, microprocessing module installed.
2. Simple pool2.py works on MAC AIR.
3. Copied to USB and copied to IMAC.
4. Terminal invocation of python to local IMAC copy fails:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pool'
5. Terminal invocation of python to attached USB copy works great.
6. Python path(s) "appear" the same on both machines.
7. Suggestions as to further diagnostics I can explore.
8. The details of the program are irrelevent as it works on MAC AIR;
9. I do import: import multiprocessing
                import time
10. In my environment (Wing Personal IDE), after pasting 'import multiprocessing' into the Python Shell, dir(multiprocessing) shows the following:['**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', 'mp', 'worker']
11. Obviously missing the guts of the module.

Comment: Do you have a multiprocessing.py file that might be imported instead of the real multiprocessing module?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section! To me your question is quite fuzzy...